# Что означает опция "Export" в настройках проекта?

Tags: android, ide, java, intellij-idea

Вопрос насчет настроек Android-проекта в IntelliJ IDEA. Если открыть `File -> Project Structure -> Modules -> <some module> -> Dependencies -> <some dependency>`, то можно увидеть опцию "Export" (чекбокс). Что вообще означает эта опция и для Android-проекта в частности?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще "Export" означает, что модули, которые зависят от того, кто экспортит, тоже могут использовать эту библиотеку.

Конкретно в Android-приложении "Export" работает так:

1. Если application-модуль ссылается на библиотеку - упаковываем.
2. Если application-модуль ссылается на Android library, а он на библиотеку, то тоже упаковываем. Может быть цепочка библиотек.
3. Если android-модуль (application или library) ссылается на обычный java-модуль, который ссылается на библиотеку, то упаковываем ее только если выбрана опция "Export". То есть в Android-приложении "Export" смотрится только в этом случае.

Answer (score 0):

Нажмите кнопку Help в том же окне - там все написано